# Magento -- auto addslashes for ajax post data

Tags: magento

I got a problem about automatic add slashes for ajax post data 
After I commit my code to test server, when I login admin, 
then Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets -> Select a attribute set -> change a group name -> click the "save attribute set" button -> view attribute set detail,　the changes can't be saved.

I dump the data var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('data')); all the double quotes are converted to \".

anyone have idea about this
sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have Magic Quotes on?

To disable Magic Quotes (as seen [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)):

in php.ini

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

or in .htaccess

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

**As always you should sanitize your data**, so i normally don't rely on magic quotes and turn it off.